# Customization of tab layout swiping direction

Tags: android, android-tabs

I've been trying to set my tabLayout to work with RTL support, but I face a problem.
in RTL (right to left), you need to swipe right to show the next page.
Currently when you swipe right it show the previous one.

I believe not many of you tried to work with RTL, so I made (ok, I tried atleast) make descriptive image to the issue - 
[image]

how I can fix that **swiping right** will show the **next page** and not previous one?
Is there any way to change the swipe direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual problem you facing is the fact, that `ViewPager` still does not support RTL.

It's well-known and very old issue - you can find it in Google's issue tracker: [ViewPager RTL swipe direction](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56831)

Recently, Booking.com's engineer [uploaded](https://github.com/diego-gomez-olvera/RtlViewPager) their `RtlViewPager`.
It's almost perfect, except the lack of `TabLayout`'s support. So I forked and fix it.

Feel free to check it out: [ksloginov/RtlViewPager](https://github.com/ksloginov/RtlViewPager)

[image]